# Switching keyboard layouts suddenly has stopped working without ANY settings change

Tags: 14.04, unity

Now I can't switch them by keyboard shortcut, only can do that with language indicator in the top panel by mouse.

Last time I faced the similar issue it was caused by filesystem fail which corrupted some unity files.

What actions would you suggest to investigate the root of the issue?

Comment: I would check first if the keyboard-shortcut still exists in the System-Properties/LanguageIndicator-Settings. Maybe any other program changed the shortcut.

Comment: I've checked, it still exists

Comment: I approve that this problem exists, I suggest someone opens a bug. I have ubuntu 14.04 with latest update, but after about 10-30 minutes after boot switching stops working and all the system hotkeys(Shift+PrtSc etc.) stop working too. So I have to manually run `setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,ru` every time to make thing work.